How to run pytest.playwright tests on a dash app wtith multiple simulated users as load test
I'd like to test my minimal dash app:
from dash import Dash, html, callback
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from time import sleep

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Button('Click me', id='button'),
    html.Div(id='output')
])


@callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    Input('button', 'n_clicks')
)
def click_and_sleep(n_clicks):
    sleep(1)
    return f'Button clicked {n_clicks} times'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8000)

with this pytest.playwright test:
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect

def test_app(page: Page):
    page.goto("http://localhost:8000/")
    page.wait_for_selector("#output")
    for n in range(3):
        page.click("#button")
        expect(page.locator("#output")).to_have_text(f"Button clicked {n+1} times")

Is there a way to use this setup so that it simulates multiple users simultaneously to load test my app?
/EDIT 1: Based on the idea from @EricLavault I build a page factory, that outputs n users:
def page_factory(
    num_users: int,
) -> list[Page]:
    pages = []
    for _ in range(num_users):
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        pages.append(page)
    return pages

and a decorator that can be wrapped around the test functions to emulate n users:
def run_with_multiple_users(num_users: int) -> Callable:
    def decorator(test_func: Callable) -> Callable:
        @wraps(test_func)
        def wrapper*args, **kwargs):
            pages = page_factory(num_users)
            for page in pages:
                test_func(page, *args, **kwargs)
                page.close()

        return wrapper

    return decorator

when I run the test now with
@run_with_multiple_users(num_users=10)
def test_app(...)
   ...

and pytest -k test_app -n 10
a browser is opened with 10 tabs, each serially making the test instead of all at once.
/EDIT 2:
instead of looping over the pages inside the decorator, I tried to use
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
   pool.map(partial(test_func, *args, **kwargs), pages)

which somehow does not get along with pickling the test function:
FAILED test_basic.py::test_app - _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function test_app at 0x7851ce61eb60>: it's not the same object as test_basic.test_app


@EricLavault I updated my code but the tests are still run serially

Just saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717519/5468372 what looks like it would the job but I don't really understand if it really does

Sorry I messed up with node.js vs python doc, the part about parallelism. And I don't see the nodejs equivalent in python (would be much simpler), yet it seems you can play with --numprocesses but it's restricted by your hardware, and it is more for running different test suites in parallel than to simulate multiple browser sessions acting on a page simultaneously (in the same test suite).

That said, if you are comfortable with js, I suggest you use playwright for node.js. Threading in Python is concurrent, but not parallel.

@EricLavault unfortunatly I'm hardly comfortable with js. What do you mean with "Threading in Python is concurrent, but not parallel"?

Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?

@see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050222/2529954, https://i.sstatic.net/pKmeqefg.png
